# Show when I last uploaded my résumé under Job preferences

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

It would be nice to see when I last uploaded my résumé under Job Preferences, that way I can easily compare it to my records and know if it's up to date.

Something like:

[image: screenshot of resume page, with the text 'last updated: 1 day ago']

Comment: Now with Free Hand Circles

Comment: Just to clarify: how would you achieve this currently? Re-download your resume and diff it to the current one? +1 it sounds like it'd be handy

Comment: @Tas you mean for people who have already uploaded a resume and don't reupload one, what date would it show for that? If so, I would hope their internal system stores a file creation or last modified date for all files.

Comment: I don't really understand the need for this feature.  Typically my resume doesn't change for past jobs, only for new or current jobs.  A visual inspection suffices.

Comment: @Kevin how can I visualize the uploaded resume?

Comment: @DaniSpringer If you uploaded your resume then you have copies of your resumes that you have uploaded? And you keep them somewhere? Could you not look at that copy? The last uploaded resume is on your SO post.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude I can look at my copies, but I don't know which version I have uploaded to SO.

Comment: And you can't tell by looking?  I have a very long resume from a long career and it's easy for me.  I'm having trouble seeing how you have so much trouble that SO should make this feature a priority.

Comment: I've looked at your LinkedIn and profile and it seems fairly straightforward.  But perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude please clarify what you understand the question to be, just to make sure we are on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the feature request, @DanielSpringer! You should be able to see when you last updated your resume under the Job preferences section.